# Mysql Cluster without replication

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

Is posible to do a MySQL Cluster without replicated database in the diferent nodes, I need to do a kind of RAC with MySQL Cluster.

In a few words I need all the nodes in the cluster pointing to the same data storage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into Mysql HA a while back. I was not able to find a satisfactory solution, but I will share my discovery nevertheless.

First of all, Mysql has very limited HA capabilities; mostly confined to async replication and clustering with semi-sync replication. The only way that I have seen that will achieve what you are looking for is to use `rsync` to do a disk level replication. Even then, you will have two copies of the data living on two different hosts.

Comment: Thanks, this is not a feasible solution for my problem. Do you know any solution like Oracle RAC with less cost ?

Comment: Check out Percona, they have some HA database products built on the Mysql core. Hopefully they have something for your use case. http://www.percona.com/